# create 5 responsive divisions using bootstra 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I am trying to create 5 responsive divisions using bootstrap 4. how i create same with 5 divisions. please check my code.

if you can please do the sample. big help

```
    <div class="col-auto">
                  <i class="fas fa-align-center"></i>
                   <label> Job code </label>
                   <label> 123456</label>
</div>


  <div class="col-auto">
                  <i class="fas fa-align-center"></i>
                   <label> Project Name </label>
                   <label> A & D Cloud implementation</label>
</div>

  <div class="col-auto">
                  <i class="fas fa-align-center"></i>
                   <label> Project Start Date </label>
                   <label> 2020-04-30</label>
</div>

  <div class="col-auto">
                  <i class="fas fa-align-center"></i>
                   <label> Task Assigned Hours: </label>
                   <label> 05</label>
</div>

  <div class="col-auto">
                  <i class="fas fa-align-center"></i>
                   <label> Task Remaining Time:  </label>
                   <label> 01.00.00</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You should review the bootstrap documentation on grid systen

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap, column classes work only inside a row. Which in turn needs a .container or .container-fluid class to work. So you can try this:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-auto"></div>
                <div class="col-auto"></div>
                <div class="col-auto"></div>  
                <div class="col-auto"></div>       
        </div>
</div>
```